# how to rebase with git lfs?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I've got a repoA with 2 lfs tracked files. I'm bringing that repo into repoB like this

```
cd repoB
git fetch repoA somebranch
git checkout -b temp FETCH_HEAD
git rebase someotherbranch
```

this prints several lines of "Applying: ..." and then

```
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Assets/HappyFunTimes/HappyFunTimesCore/Server/Resources/HFTOSXServer.bytes
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0340 update server
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

How do I fix this? **NOTE: THIS FILE DOES NOT EXIST IN repoA**. This issue seems to be entirely related to issues with git lfs.

git status showed this

```
$ git status
rebase in progress; onto 5af1f30
You are currently rebasing branch 'gamepad' on '5af1f30'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Assets/HappyFunTimes/HappyFunTimesCore/Server/Resources/HFTOSXServer.bytes
    deleted:    Assets/HappyFunTimes/HappyFunTimesCore/Server/Resources/HFTOSXServer.sha256.bytes

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Note: I tried just adding and committing the 2 files (voodoo) and then `git rebase --continue` which kept going until the next time the file was modified in the history at which point it got a similar error. I did the same thing and it finally finished. But then when I tried to rebase that onto another branch I got

```
Downloading Assets/HappyFunTimes/HappyFunTimesCore/Server/Resources/HFTOSXServer.bytes (7.48 MB)
Error downloading object: Assets/HappyFunTimes/HappyFunTimesCore/Server/Resources/HFTOSXServer.bytes (4743b094eeab821140773213ebabdaa81c9ac2eb1be1108e70e8d51ae52873dd)

Errors logged to /Users/gregg/src/hft-unity3d/.git/lfs/objects/logs/20160603T213456.110362284.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed 2
error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed
fatal: Assets/HappyFunTimes/HappyFunTimesCore/Server/Resources/HFTOSXServer.bytes: smudge filter lfs failed
Could not apply dc378b5d715103e9af0ee805ff2a3be1159739aa... add lfs support
```

Which kind of suggests I have no clue how to use git lfs correctly.

### update 1

So it turns out you have to install git lfs in every repo. This is not at all clear from [the docs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) which say

> You only have to set up Git LFS once.
>
> ```
>  git lfs install
> ```

It turns out it's once per repo not actually *once*.

Then, reading though [the issues](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/) it needs to know where to get the remotely stored files. It does this based on whatever remote branch is being tracked so, starting over

```
git clone git@github.com/me/repoA
cd repoA
git lfs install
git remote add repoB git@github.com/me/repoB
git fetch repoB
git checkout -b temp repoB/somebranch
```

This starts to checkout repoB/somebranch into a temp but fails with

```
Downloading Assets/HappyFunTimes/HappyFunTimesCore/Server/Resources/HFTOSXServer.bytes (7.48 MB)
Error downloading object: Assets/HappyFunTimes/HappyFunTimesCore/Server/Resources/HFTOSXServer.bytes (f8c42a7c55f610768ce50ff93d09fc63fa897de867290dafee2e84d64e10de4e)

Errors logged to /Users/gregg/temp/delme-hft-unity3d/.git/lfs/objects/logs/20160603T231351.670335751.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed 2
error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed
fatal: Assets/HappyFunTimes/HappyFunTimesCore/Server/Resources/HFTOSXServer.bytes: smudge filter lfs failed
```

AFAIK I'm tracking the correct branch now. That's the same branch on the same remote that the files were uploaded with.

### update 2

Starting over with the last one but changing `origin` to point to the repoB after cloning repoA gets further

```
git clone git@github.com/me/repoA
cd repoA
git lfs install
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@github.com/me/repoB
git fetch repoB
git checkout -b temp origin/somebranch
```

This works where as before it failed

But now

```
git checkout -b other master
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/somebranch
git rebase master temp
```

Fails at the same place as before

```
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Assets/HappyFunTimes/HappyFunTimesCore/Server/Resources/HFTOSXServer.bytes
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0358 update server
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted. git-lfs is relatively new. The docs are sparse. Doesn't it seem likely other people are going to run into these issues as it gets more popular and need a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Okay apparently the issue is when git calls hooks it doesn't pass the current tracking branch info so lfs has no way to find the files. It just defaults to using `origin`'s link

So to do this you need to install lfs with the `--skip-smudge` option. this will basically tell lfs not to download the files. Do the merges as expected, then `git lfs pull` which has a remote parameter to let you tell it where to get the files

Once it's all done I'm assuming you can type `git lfs install` to get it somewhat back to normal. You probably need to do a `git lfs fetch --all repoB` and `git lfs push --all repoA somebranch` to get all your the files you downloaded from the previous repo's lfs store (repoB) to the new repo's lfs store (repoA)

all the steps [from this github issue](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/1287#issuecomment-223672558)

```
# This disables smudging for the 'git clone'
# and then calls 'git lfs pull' for you
git lfs clone git@github.com:me/repoB.git
cd repoB
git lfs install --skip-smudge --local # affects only this clone

git fetch repoA
git checkout -b temp repoA/somebranch
git rebase master

git lfs fetch --all repoA
git lfs checkout
git push origin temp

git lfs push --all origin temp
git lfs install --force --local
```

The `git lfs pull` command is essentially the same as calling `git lfs fetch` (downloads LFS objects) and `git lfs checkout` (copies the locally downloaded files to your working directory). So, my example only downloads objects through the `git lfs fetch --all` command.

If you want to disable the smudge filter for a single command, you can also use `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE`:

```
$ GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 git pull
$ git lfs pull
```

Comment: This worked for me in a slightly different order, but the key was to
```
git lfs install --skip-smudge --local
# do whatever git command was failing, for me it was checking out a fetched branch
git lfs checkout # grab the lfs files associated with the checkout
git lfs install --force --local # reinstall regular lfs usage
```

Answer (score 0):

The commit from `repoA` modified the file `Assets/HappyFunTimes/HappyFunTimesCore/Server/Resources/HFTOSXServer.bytes`.

This same file is also in `repoB` working tree. Git awares you that it can't replace the file. To correct it, you have to do what git is suggesting. Git often telling you how to correct the error.

Stash or commit your local changes. In your case it seems better to stash your changes, do the rebase, pop the stash. That give you the following commands.

```
cd repoB
git stash
git fetch repoA somebranch
git checkout -b temp FETCH_HEAD
git rebase someotherbranch
git stash pop // You may need to resolve conflict using git mergetool
```

Before to start, be sure to avoid the previous rebase attempts.

Comment: thanks but the file does not exist in repoA whatsoever. The entire path does not exist in repoA. The error has something to do with git lfs (or I assume). You can see [repoA here](https://github.com/greggman/hft-unity3d/tree/0546effaf02463a63b651325cb648c904cc02421) in the state before I got this to work. You can see there is no `Assets` folder in the root.